# Getting InvalidSelectorException while trying to locate the child nodes of an element using union operator(|)

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate the last div or last h1 children of the div node.

**HTML code:**

```
<html><head></head><body>

<div>
<div class="a x">Foo</div>
<span>Delhi</span>
<div class="b x">Bar</div>
<div class="c x">Baz</div>
<span>ABC</span>

<div>
<div class="d x">Foo</div>
<span>Mumbai</span><br>
<h1>DEF</h1>
</div>

</div>
</body></html>
```

**Selenium code:**

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("/descendant-or-self::node()/child::div/(child::h1 | child::div)[position()=last()]")).size());
```

It is throwing `InvalidSelectorException: Given xpath expression "/descendant-or-self::node()/child::div/(child::h1 | child::div)[position()=last()]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`

As per https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-sets, `The | operator computes the union of its operands, which must be node-sets.`

Please help.

Comment: from the HTML you can just use //h1

Comment: Certainly Xpath is wrong. What exactly you are trying to locate in above HTML ?

Comment: @slackingslacker: Thanks for reply. I am trying to locate the node based on its parent node. Also, I want to understand how to use the union operator.

Comment: @rahulrai: I am trying to locate the last div or last h1 children of the div node using union operator.

Comment: Well there are others methods to get your desired result. However as you wanted to use union operator I have written XPath using the same. Please see the answer section.

Comment: @Pavan Happy to help. Well you can upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message suggest your xPath expression is not correct. Issue is with the way you have used union operator (|). As union operator (|), operator returns the union of its two operands, which must be node-sets. You can use like below:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::div/child::h1[position()=last()] | /descendant-or-self::node()/child::div/child::div[position()=last()]
```

See the difference. in the position of |.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for the clarification on how to use union`(|)` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but your xpath expression is too complicated, I believe. So you may be looking for something like:

```
//div//div/(span[position()=last()]| h1[position()=last()])
```

You should try it on a html sample that has more than one `h1`, for example.

Comment: This is throwing same exception. But the solution provided by Rahul Rai is working.